# Handling Missing Not At Random Data

Tags: missing-data, binary-data

I'm working with a data set from here: https://nij.ojp.gov/funding/recidivism-forecasting-challenge

To put it simply, it is a binary classification problem. The gang affiliation variable is pretty useful, but it is only recorded for men, making this a missing not at random data, with the missingness completely correlated with the gender variable.

I'd like to use both gender and gang affiliation variable along with other variables.

Could someone point me to the resources to handle this kind of missing data?

I'm thinking of fitting a logistic regression model and a Bayesian model.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds to me like missing at random, not MNAR. However, I don't see how you can deal with this without making some pretty hefty assumptions about mechanisms of gang membership being equal across gender, which seems very unlikely to me. If it's a predictor, then you dummy code three groups: male (gang member), male (non-gang member), female.

Comment: @JeremyMiles ah I read the definition wrong about MNAR, thanks for correcting that. But yes, I think it's probably best to dummy code it like you said, thank you.